# How many diamonds can a Diamond Ore drop in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I are having an argument on how many diamonds a Diamond Ore can drop (on avg. or maximum) without any fortune levels on a pickaxe.
My friend says there will always drop only one, but I'm fairly certain that's not true. Tested in singleplayer, I've had a few times where diamond ores have dropped 2 diamonds while having absolutely no modifications installed.

Answer (score 21):

I hate to break it to you, but your friend is correct here.  Without any sort of enchantments or mods, [diamond ore only drops 1 diamond](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_ore#Usage).  There's a high likelihood that you might have simply miscounted the number of ores you mined in single player.

Note that the average number of diamonds with a Fortune enchantment are 1.33, 1.75, and 2.2 for Fortune I, II, and III respectively.

Answer (score 13):

Well... Acording to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond#Mining) :

> Diamond ore mined using an iron or diamond pickaxe will drop a **single** diamond.

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer: Your friend is right, you are wrong.

With no enchantments, a single diamond ore will drop a single diamond, no exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

A block of diamond ore drops a single diamond without modifications. However, if you enchant your pick with fortune 3, you can get up to 4 diamonds from a single block!

Comment: I’m pretty sure it drops 3 diamonds at max. I don’t know, I haven’t seen 4 diamonds come out of one diamond ore.

Answer (score -3):

I think your correct. I was just playing my minwcraft world and found a vein of 8 diamonds. I mined it with no fortune or looting on an iron pickaxe and somehow got 10 diamonds. Also I play on PS4 so I cant add mods.

Comment: You are very wrong. Diamonds can only drop one per ore. Also, you cant actually add looting to a pickaxe.